# Cloudflare ignores/removes some parts of the frontend code every few days

Tags: javascript, caching, next.js, cloudflare

I have a problem with Cloudflare - it ocassionaly breaks the frontend of the website and it happens every few days. It eliminates or ignores some parts of the frontend code (Next.js).

It happens on the multiple places, like for example the Navigation bar has multiple links in the account dropdown (Account Info, Portal 1, Portal 2 and Sign Out), but after a few days only one link (Sign Out) is shown. Also, some internal APIs from the backend (django) are not working.

After I purge cache (Purge Everything) on Cloudflare, it works fine for the next couple of days.

I tried to disable Auto Minify on Cloudflare but the issue is still there.

Thank you in advance!

I tried disabling Auto Minify Code which was previously enabled, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.